# Microsoft Azure - php

Tags: php, wordpress, microsoft-azure, plugin-wordpress, application-insights

Como fazer com que o Microsoft Azure capture meus erros?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu atualmente estou tratando os erros com essa função:

```
<?php


/**
  Plugin Name: TESTE
  Description: testando log novo
  Version: 1.0
  Author: Vteste
  Author URI: teste

  -------
  LICENSE: This file is subject to the terms and conditions defined in
  file 'license.txt', which is part of Advanced Access Manager source package.
 *
 */

// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        $erro = "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        $erro += "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        $erro += ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        $erro += "Aborting...<br />\n";
        echo $erro;
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        $erro = "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        $erro = "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr\n";
        break;

    default:
        $erro = "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr, linha:$errline, no arquivo $errfile";
            error_log($erro);
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// function to test the error handling
function scale_by_log($vect, $scale)
{
    if (!is_numeric($scale) || $scale <= 0) {
        trigger_error("log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (!is_array($vect)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect input vector, array of values expected", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }

    $temp = array();
    foreach($vect as $pos => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            trigger_error("Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero)", E_USER_NOTICE);
            $value = 0;
        }
        $temp[$pos] = log($scale) * $value;
    }

    return $temp;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");


?>
```

E utilizo o plugin do *Application Insights | Microsoft Azure*, porém ele não está coletando nenhum tipo de erro, então gostaria de enviar manualmente como poderia fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho certeza, mas creio que seja devido ao:

```
return true;
```

Dentro do seu *handler* no `set_error_handler` tem o `return true;`, isto faz ao invés de usar o handler interno ele usar somente o teu "handler", então LOG interno do PHP nunca consegue pegar o erro, porque você esta impedindo.

Para tentar resolver remova o `return true;`, um detalhe a própria [Microsoft disponibiliza uma API para usa do Application Insights](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP), se estiver usando `composer` pode instalar assim:

```
require: "microsoft/application-insights": "*"
```

Note que é necessário estar usando PHP 5.4.2+

Após instalar [crie uma chave](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/wiki#getting-an-application-insights-instrumentation-key) e adicione este código com sua chave:

```
$telemetryClient = new \ApplicationInsights\Telemetry_Client();
$telemetryClient->getContext()->setInstrumentationKey('DIGITE SUA CHAVE AQUI');
$telemetryClient->trackEvent('name of your event');
$telemetryClient->flush();
```

Comment: Funciona com multisite ??

Comment: @KaueAlves multi-dominios ou multi-sites?

Comment: multisites do wordpress

Comment: @KaueAlves não sei afirmar, se o multi-site forem aplicações wordpress diferentes creio que terá que configurar um a um, se for a mesma aplicação com múltiplos domínios talvez não seja necessário.